# How do I put Content dynamically in a control

Tags: wpf, xaml, stackpanel, dynamicresource

I have two almost identical GUI structurs in XAML, the difference is in one StackPanel that have an Image and a Rectangle in respective structure, the StackPanel contains other content as well. I want to only write the hole structure once and have a dynamic resource where a put the Image or Rectangle. The code will basicly be like:

```
<Style x:Key="myGrid" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <!-- Many nested controls -->
        <StackPanel>
            <!-- Some differnt Controls -->
            <Object Value="{DynamicResource someDynamicItem}" />
        <StackPanel/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="myGridWithImage" BasedOn="{StaticResource myGrid}" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="someDynamicItem" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="myGridWithRectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource myGrid}" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Rectangle x:Key="someDynamicItem" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Is it possibly to have any kind of placeholder (instead of the Object-Tag) that could be dynamically assigned in this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a content control in your grid and then can have its content set based on some  condition, if that condition is not met you can either choose to not set the content or may be make its visibility collapsed.

I recommend content control over stack panel in you case, so that in future if you have a requirement to fit in something else you just need to provide a new content to content control.